Is it possible to base a type on keys defined in a JS object in TypeScript?
interface SomeThing {
    a: string
    b: string
    c: string
}

const fields: Partial<Record<keyof SomeThing, boolean>> = {
  a: true,
  b: false,
}

type ExtractFields<T, F> = {
  [K in keyof F]-?: F[K] extends true ? K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never : never;
}

type Result = ExtractFields<SomeThing, typeof fields>

Playground
My goal is Result to be:
type Result {
  a: string
}

Instead it results in:
type Result = {
    a: never;
    b: never;
    c: never;
}

It's like F[K] can't resolve to true even if defined as true in F[K] extends true.

Let's fix it piece-wise.
First let's keep the type of fields:
const fields = {
  a: true,
  b: false,
} satisfies Partial<Record<keyof SomeThing, boolean>>

This gives you:
type Result = {
    a: string;
    b: never;
}

Now let's improve ExtractFields to include only the keys mapped to true.
type ExtractFields2<T, F> = {
  [K in keyof F as F[K] extends true? K : never]-?: K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never;
}
type Result2 = ExtractFields2<SomeThing, typeof fields>

This gives you expected:
type Result2 = {
    a: string;
}

Complete code:
interface SomeThing {
    a: string
    b: string
    c: string
}

const fields = {
  a: true,
  b: false,
} satisfies Partial<Record<keyof SomeThing, boolean>>

type ExtractFields<T, F> = {
  [K in keyof F]-?: F[K] extends true ? K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never : never;
}

type Result = ExtractFields<SomeThing, typeof fields>


type ExtractFields2<T, F> = {
  [K in keyof F as F[K] extends true? K : never]-?: K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never;
}
type Result2 = ExtractFields2<SomeThing, typeof fields>

